# netbeans, jar file not updating after recompiling

Tags: java, netbeans

I built a busch-league GUI with net beans.  Next to jar file it says date modified: 10:30am which hours ago!

Whether or not that is typical, the fact is my classes are updated in netbeans but not updated in the jar file because the program doesn't work correctly when double clicking on it.

Comment: Did you build it again?

Comment: Did you enable the project option "Build jar after compiling"? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40938_01/doc.74/e40142/build_japps.htm#BABDFECB

Comment: Let me shorten this up.  why is my code updating and functioning in the IDE but not in the jar?